# How does the lighting cable work plugged in any way round?

Tags: iphone, lightning

Sorry titled this one badly, I'm assuming power is the two centre pins, then data is the rest, but surely it's messed up when the cable is plugged in backwards?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_(connector)?wprov=sfsi1

Answer (score 4):

Per [this site](http://pinouts.ru/CellularPhones-A-N/apple_lightning_pinout.shtml):

[image]

> Apple Lightning interface is adaptive - the controller chip dynamically assign pins function according to plugged device.
>
> The Apple Lightning connector plug can be inserted with either side
>   facing up (the processor inside the plug detects the plug's
>   orientation and routes the electrical signals to the correct pins).Two
>   differential pair lanes (L0p/n and L1p/n) may swap in IC of device
>   connector (lanes don't swap if accessory identification chip connect
>   to ID0 pin).

[image]

Comment: Would that explain the chip in the lighting cable?

Comment: Yes, in addition to security and authentication capabilities.  [This site](https://www.chipworks.com/about-chipworks/overview/blog/inside-apple-lightning-cable) has more info about the cable and chip.

Comment: @fsb That site no longer has that page, last archived version I could find is [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20190521000230/http://www.chipworks.com/about-chipworks/overview/blog/inside-apple-lightning-cable).

Answer (score 0):

From: [Systems Analysis of the Apple Lightning to USB Cable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aek8F.jpg)

> The BQ2025’s one data pin is connected to two Lightning cable pins.
>   Why two? Recall that the Lightning cable is designed to work no matter
>   which way it is inserted into the phone (USB anyone?). Some may call
>   it lazy to not have to think when plugging something in, but we feel
>   that it is a subtle improvement in usability that shows attention to
>   detail.
>
> The figure below shows the Lightning cable in two orientations
>   (there’s a little white triangle on the diagram to help you visualize
>   the rotation). The coloured lines indicate electrically equivalent
>   pins. We know from our circuit board analysis that the BQ2025 connects
>   to the black signal. Effectively then, the BQ2025 is connected to two
>   Lightning cable pins. We’ve labelled them A1 and B5.
>
> The phone itself only monitors the bottom row of pins. If the user has
>   inserted the cable right-side-up, the phone needs to use the pin,
>   which is fifth from the left, to communicate with the BQ2025. That’s
>   where the black signal is. Furthermore, if the user has inserted the
>   cable upside-down (or is it right-side-up?), the phone needs to use
>   the left-most pin. The BQ2025’s one data pin is connected to two
>   Lightning cable pins. Why two? Recall that the Lightning cable is
>   designed to work no matter which way it is inserted into the phone
>   (USB anyone?). Some may call it lazy to not have to think when
>   plugging something in, but we feel that it is a subtle improvement in
>   usability that shows attention to detail.

[image: From: https://www.chipworks.com/sites/default/files/wpblog/2pin-config-4.jpg]